# co-relation with multiple categorical variables

Tags: statistics, data-science, data-analysis

Is there a method to find a co-relation between multiple categorical variables? when you have a very big data set with a lot of categorical variables.

Comment: Check out Cramér's V: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_V 
& Theil’s U: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_coefficient

Answer (score 0):

as @arpitrathi mentioned, typically you need to use Cramer's V.
AS I remember, there are already prepared code snippets on the internet,
I will leave you the one I am typically using for this, maybe it will help you.

You will need to import some libs to use it.

```
from scipy import stats
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

def cramers_v(x, y):
    '''
    Returns cramers_v for 2 categorical features
    '''
    confusion_matrix = pd.crosstab(x,y)
    chi2 = stats.chi2_contingency(confusion_matrix)[0]
    n = confusion_matrix.sum().sum()
    phi2 = chi2/n
    r,k = confusion_matrix.shape
    phi2corr = max(0, phi2-((k-1)*(r-1))/(n-1))
    rcorr = r-((r-1)**2)/(n-1)
    kcorr = k-((k-1)**2)/(n-1)
    return np.sqrt(phi2corr/min((kcorr-1),(rcorr-1)))


def heatmap_categorical_columns_w_dependant_categorical(df, dependent_variable, columns):
    '''
    Takes df, a dependant variable as str
    Returns a heatmap of catecorical columns cramers_v with dependent variable 
    '''
    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 10))
    corrM = [cramers_v(df[dependent_variable], df[column]) for column in columns]
    corr = pd.DataFrame(corrM, index=columns, columns=[dependent_variable])
    ax = sns.heatmap(corr,
            annot=True,
            cmap='coolwarm', 
            vmin=-1,
            vmax=1,
           )
    ax.set_title("Cramer V Correlation between Variables")
    return ax
```

The result will be something like:
[image]

Example of usage you can check out in this code:
https://github.com/OzmundSedler/IBM-advanced-DS-coursera/blob/master/4%20Capstone%20/ML-project-draft.ipynb

Comment: thanks for the code. As is know phi2 is used for binary variables. can we also use phi2 for calulationg the cramer' V for multiple category variables?

Comment: @JUNAID ASGHAR Check out the code here: https://www.kaggle.com/phaethonprime/eda-and-logistic-regression

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to get correlations among multiple variables using plt.matshow. Where 'bikesharing_data' is the pandas DataFrame.

```
    plt.figure(figsize=[12, 8])
    plt.matshow(bikesharing_data.corr(),
    fignum=False,
    aspect='equal')

    columns = len(bikesharing_data.columns)

    plt.xticks(range(columns), bikesharing_data.columns)
    plt.yticks(range(columns), bikesharing_data.columns)

    plt.colorbar() 
    plt.xticks(rotation=90)
    plt.title('Correlation', y=1.2)

    plt.show()
```

Where you can drop the numerical variables using:

```
    features = bikesharing_data.drop(['x1', 'x2', ... ,'xn'], axis=1)
```

The resultant output is as follows;
[Correlation Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqjWJ.png)